# How can I build sbt against RPM-installed (system) libraries?

Tags: sbt, rpm

I'm interested in building an RPM package for sbt 0.12.3 that meets the [Fedora packaging guidelines](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging%3aGuidelines).  In order to do this, I'll need to be able to build sbt itself against libraries that were built from source and installed via RPM packages.

Java packages in Fedora that use Ivy are able to resolve RPM-installed artifacts by disabling network resolvers and resolving all packages from `/usr/share/java/[artifact].[ext]` -- see [here](https://github.com/pdmack/zookeeper/blob/release-3.4.2-f18/ivysettings.xml) for an example.

I think I understand how to override default resolvers in sbt using a [boot properties](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Launcher.html) file, but this is where I run in to a problem:  if I set the Ivy directory to `/usr/share/java`, sbt expects to be able to publish artifacts to this directory (not merely to look for existing artifacts there), which I don't want it to do (both in general and for this specific case of RPM building).  If I specify `file:///usr/share/java` as a proxy location (following Mark's instructions below), sbt will fail (citing the absence of `ivy.xml` in that location).

I am able to find locally-installed dependencies by modifying `project/p.sbt` to point to explicit URLs (e.g. `"org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.7.1" from "file:///usr/share/java/jsoup.jar"`), but this doesn't work for scala and the scala library (and is obviously not the right thing to do in general).

How can I build sbt against (and only against) locally-installed, RPM-managed system Scala and libraries?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Proxy-Repositories.html?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  But the problem I'm having is that I'm interested in building against system libraries (installed in a read-only directory on the local filesystem) without spinning up a proxy.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Although it says proxy in the title, you don't actually need one.  A filesystem resolver is fine.

Comment: When I do this, it appears that sbt expects an `ivy.xml` file in the filesystem location that has the RPM-managed jars.  Concretely, if I specify a resolver as `file:///usr/share/java, [artifact].[ext]`, sbt will fail to find the jars that are there and warn that it tried `file:/usr/share/java/ivy.xml`.

Comment: I think adding `,mavenCompatible` should work.  See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Launcher.html#grammar-token-customRepository and https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/585.

Comment: If I add `,mavenCompatible` to the resolver it still fails in the same way, warning that it tried `file:/usr/share/java/ivy.xml`.  Interestingly, ant projects that depend on these artifacts (specified with these patterns) are buildable, so I'm wondering if I'm just missing an sbt setting somewhere.